# SML: Rigorous Way To Parenthesize Function Type

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to parenthesize a function (when it's legal to add parentheses around certain parts to make the meaning clearer).

For instance, `foldl` is defined as having type:

```
foldl : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

Now, if I look at `foldl`'s definition, I see:

```
fun foldl g z [] = z
    | foldl g z (x::L) = foldl g (g(x,z)) L;
```

Based on this, I usually just mentally map `g` to `('a * 'b -> 'b)`, `z` to be of type `'b`, and pattern-matching takes care of the list of type `'a list`.  Finally, the return type is `'b`.

However, I thought `->` right associates, so wouldn't it be most natural to start by saying "OK, add parentheses like so:

```
foldl : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> ('a list -> 'b)
```

What's wrong with this line of thought / what am I misunderstanding about how to add parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it, it's just redundant.

`('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> ('a list -> 'b)`, `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> ('b -> ('a list -> 'b))` and `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b` are all equivalent *because* `->` is right associative. So we usually write the version with the least parentheses (just like one usually writes `3 - 2 - 1` rather than the equivalent `(3 - 2) - 1`).